# Problems writing to a nested array of objects in Angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I have a model component that defines the data structure that I'm using.  I then use that model in another component and try to write data to it.  I'm having challenges writing to the 'nested' object array in my data structure.  I'm pretty sure it's because I haven't declared the nested array correctly (instantiated it) but can't quite figure out how to do it properly.  No question it's a limitation in my knowledge but after thrashing on it for several hours I figured I'd reach out for help.  Any guidance would be appreciated.

Simplified stackblitz below...
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bgk5fo

```js
export class Adventure {
  id ? : string;
  companylogo: string;
  guideavatar: string;
  quizavatar: string;
  active: boolean;
  treasureimage: string;
  poi: [{
    completedflag: boolean;
    firsthint: string;
    secondhint: string;
    thirdhint: string;
    quizanswer: string;
    quizfail: string;
    quizoptionone: string;
    quizoptiontwo: string;
    quizoptionthree: string;
    quizquestion: string;
    quizsuccess: string;
    sortorder: number;
    target: string;
  }];
}

import {
  Component
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  DataModel
} from './data.model'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular';

  testModel = new DataModel();

  createArray() {
    this.testModel.firstname = 'Jack';
    this.testModel.lastname = 'Brown';
    this.testModel.pet[0].petalive = true;
    this.testModel.pet[0].petname = 'Whiskers';
    this.testModel.pet[0].pettype = 'Cat'
  }




}
```

Comment: Please paste direct meaningful parts of the code that are giving you problems. That way, when your question is answered, it will help other people with the same problem.

Comment: Sure thing, anything I can do to help.  I'm still new to the StackOverflow world and didn't even know stackblitz existed prior to a post I made a few days ago. ;)  Will include a bit of code in this post as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are some fundamental issues with your code.

I believe you want to make use of `DataModel` as for structural typing. Therefore, if you wanna define a class/interface for type checking, your data.model.ts should be defined this way:

```
export interface DataModel {
  firstname: string;
  lastname: string;
  pet: Array<Pet>;
}

interface Pet {
  petname: string;
  pettype: string;
  petalive: boolean;
}
```

On your component.ts, you will need to initialise and define your `testModel` (of type `DataModel`). On your createArray() method, you can simply assign the properties this way:

```
testModel: DataModel = {
    firstname: undefined,
    lastname: undefined,
    pet: []
  };

createArray(){
  this.testModel.firstname = 'Jack';
  this.testModel.lastname = 'Brown';
  this.testModel.pet.push({
    petalive: true,
    petname: 'Whiskers',
    pettype: 'Cat'
  });
  console.log(this.testModel);  
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to provide a response!  I am familiar with the concept of interfaces but never actually used them (properly) before so this looks like a great opportunity to do so!

Comment: You are welcome :) Yup! In this scenario, when you are defining data models, it is recommended to use Interface rather than Class. In addition, I created a separate interface `Pet` for your `pet` property. It is much cleaner than explicitly defining it on your class/interface!

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution with array is type any

> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-shotgr?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Hope that it's help for you

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LglWi.png)

Comment: Thanks so much for your response!  This looks like an interesting option for solving the problem.